# Correct handling of type-dependent logic (highly polymorphic objects) inside of abstract logic using OOP

Tags: c#, oop

What is the best way from point of OOP to handle mapping from Game object to GameDto object, taking into account that Game has property Scoreboard that has a lot of derived objects (more than 15) as FootballScoreboard, Formula1Scoreboard, BaseballScoreboard, etc?

There is ability to know what exact type of Scoreboard inside of game only in runtime (it can be for whatever sport).
ScoreboardDto has corresponding FootballScoreboardDto, Formula1ScoreboardDto, BaseballScoreboardDto, etc classes.

The simplified scheme:

```
public class Game 
{
    public Scoreboard Scoreboard { get; }
}

public class GameDto
{
    public ScoreboardDto Scoreboard { get; }
}


public class DtoParser 
{
    public GameDto Parse(Game game)
    {
        var gameDto = new GameDto();
        //How to implement parsing of game.Scoreboard in the best way here????
    }
}
```

The main goal is to avoid if-else chains and switch-cases, since it's bad practice in OOP.

The possible solution what I see:
use some kind of ScoreboardParserFactory that returns necessary scoreboard parser depending on the scoreboard type.
Like:

```
var parser = _scoreboardParserFactory.Create(game.Scoreboard);
gameDto.Scoreboard = parser.Parse(game.Scoreboard);
```

But there are still the disadvantages:
1) It still doesn't look like I'll be able to make any implementation using only IoC and without long if-else/switch-case like:

```
if (scoreboard.GetType() == typeof(FootballScoreboard)) return new FootballScoreboardParser()
else if (scoreboard.GetType() == typeof(Formula1Scoreboard)) return new Formula1ScoreboardParser()
else ...
```

2) I'll still have to make explicit type conversion inside of parser's Parse method, like:

```
public class FootballScoreboardParser
{
    public ScoreboardDto Parse(Scoreboard scoreboard) 
    {
        var footballScoreboard = (FootballScoreboard) scoreboard;
        return new FootballScoreboardDto() {/*...*/};
    }
}
```

Is any better way to implement the conversion from terms of high quality OOP code (without explicit type conversions and long if-else/switch-case)? Maybe there is any standard way of handling such cases? Any help from IoC in this?

Comment: This is exactly what IoC addresses. Use a container and register the parser for each type, then request from the container. No need for `if` statements.

Comment: @JuanRomero, thank you for the comment.Agree regarding IoC, but what about implementation of parsers (for ex. FootballScoreboardParser), we still will have to use explict type conversion, no any other ways, right? Isn't there any more beautiful approaches for implementation of this, without explicit type conversion (which is often recognized as smell code)?

Comment: You can achieve what you want using generics. Is the game the same or does it also vary?

Comment: @Juan Romer, game is the same (no derived supposed)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using generic interfaces:

```
public class DtoParserFactory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IDtoParser> _parsers = new Dictionary<Type, IDtoParser>();

    public void Register(Type type, IDtoParser parser)
    {
        _parsers.Add(type, parser);
    }

    public IDtoParser GetParser(IScoreBoard scoreBoard)
    {
        var type = scoreBoard.GetType();
        var parser = _parsers[type];
        return parser;
    }
}

public class SomeScoreboardParser : BaseScoreBoardParser<SomeScoreboard, ScoreboardDto>
{
    public override ScoreboardDto Parse(SomeScoreboard scoreBoard)
    {
        return new ScoreboardDto();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseScoreBoardParser<TScoreBoard, TDto> : IDtoParser<TScoreBoard, TDto> where TScoreBoard : IScoreBoard where TDto: IDto
{
    public abstract TDto Parse(TScoreBoard scoreBoard);
    public IDto Parse(IScoreBoard scoreBoard)
    {
        return Parse((TScoreBoard)scoreBoard);
    }
}

public interface IDtoParser<TScoreBoard, TDto> : IDtoParser
    where TScoreBoard : IScoreBoard
    where TDto : IDto
{
    TDto Parse(TScoreBoard scoreBoard);
}

public interface IDtoParser
{
    IDto Parse(IScoreBoard scoreBoard);
}

public class ScoreboardDto : IDto
{

}

public interface IDto
{

}
```

Then consume it:

```
var game = new Game();            
DtoParserFactory factory = new DtoParserFactory();
factory.Register(typeof(SomeScoreboard), new SomeScoreboardParser());
var parser = factory.GetParser(game.Scoreboard);
var dto = parser.Parse(game.Scoreboard);
```

You just need to register your types in the factory and it will resolve them for you. This is the line that does that in the code sample:

```
factory.Register(typeof(SomeScoreboard), new SomeScoreboardParser());
```

This is [obviously] an oversimplified example I wrote on the fly. There are a few things that can be improved. This is just meant to illustrate the point.

Comment: thank you for the comment again. Your example actually is a bit different from my case - as I told in the description there is an ability to know what time of the scoreboard only in runtime, so I cannot write things like: 

DoGame<SomeScoreboard>();
Let's say I have a list of games that I need to parse, and every game may have its own type of scoreboard.

Comment: I suspect that in my case there is no way to avoid explicit type conversion in parsers ?..

Comment: @TOL: OK. I modified the example to work the way you want it.

Comment: Juan, thank you for the answer. It's the most beautiful and safe usage of explicit type conversion, but it's still explicit type conversion (here I mean: return Parse((TScoreBoard)scoreBoard);). Do you think it's fine to use such kind of things (as explicit type conversion) in well OOP designed application? Is it the best implementation what possible to do in such case?